# Several Controllers for a single Route

Tags: ember.js

I'm a beginner in Ember, as far as I know, for a route, there can be only one controller, suppose I have a webapp with the layout below, in the right and left side column, i'll have a widget and in the Main Column, i'll have interface. I'll want to have a controller manage the right,left and Main column, can this be achieved in Ember?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it can be done.

Comment: is it using View, and then displaying the View in specific part of the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The thing you need to understand to achieve this is embers handlebars `{{outlet}}` helper. By default the Router will fill the outlet with the appropriate template backed by the appropriate controller based on the route you are on. However you are able to modify this default behaviour like so:

*Step1: Provide multiple outlets in your application.hbs and name them.*

```
{{outlet sideBarLeft}}
{{outlet}}
{{outlet sideBarRight}}
```

*Step2: Tell the application route how to fill those outlets with templates/controllers.*

```
App.ApplicationRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('leftStuff', {    // the template to render
      into: 'application',        // the template to render into
      outlet: 'sideBarLeft',      // the name of the outlet in that template
      controller: 'leftStuff'     // the controller to use for the template
    });
    this.render('rightStuff', {
      into: 'application',
      outlet: 'sideBarRight',
      controller: 'rightStuff'
    });
  }
});
```

Now ember should always fill the bars on the left and right with the specified templates/controllers and the main area should default to the current route (i.e. it should change whenever you navigate through the page). *I hope this is what you want, feel free to comment with your findings if they differ from my solution so that i can update my answer.*

If this is not working out of the box i recommend you to check out the [{{outlet}} api](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_outlet) and the [templating guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) on ember.js. They provide code examples for quite a lot use cases.